# jQuery .click() doesn't fire but onclick does

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a $each loop in jquery that adds rows into a table like this:

```
                $.each(result, function (index) {
                    var data = result[index];
                    cameraIcon = GetCameraIcon();
                    cameraIcon = cameraIcon.replace("$cameraId", data.CameraFQID);                       
                    var tr = "<tr><td>" + cameraIcon + "</td><td>" + icon + '</td><td>' + timestamp.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss') + '</td><td>' + data.DeviceLink + '</td><td>' + data.EventMessage + '</td><td>' + data.CardId + '</td></tr>';
                    $('#eventTable tr:first').after(tr);
                });

    function GetCameraIcon() {            
        return "<a href='javascript:;' class='cameraButton' id='$cameraId'><i class=\'fa fa-camera\'></i></a>";
    }
```

My question is: why doesn't my jquery method fire?

```
$(".cameraButton").click(function () {
            alert('clicked')
        });
```

However, when I do this:

```
<a href='javascript:;' onclick=\"alert('clicked')\">
```

It works.

My guess is some careless mistake somewhere but I can't pinpoint or figure it out

Comment: It doesn't look like you have an element with a .cameraButton class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably event delegation. The new rows added to the table were not present when jQuery bound to its events, so you must use `.on()` to trap the events.

Try:

```
$(document).on("click", ".cameraButton", function () {
     alert('clicked');
});
```

Remember to add semi-colon to end of statements.

Answer (score 1):

If you add elements dynamically then you need to use delegated events trough [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method. This should do the trick

```
$(document).on('click', '.cameraButton', function() {
    ...
}
```

Direct events won't work since elements need to already exist on your page by the time you execute the statement `$(".cameraButton").click(function () {}`.

Take into account that `$(".cameraButton")` returns an empty array in case there no element yet with class `.cameraButton` so click is bound to nothing.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
document.getElementById("cameraId").addEventListener("click", function(){
alert("Hello World!");
});
```